# PasteSpecial Method of Range Class Failed after Copying

Tags: excel, vba

Here is a snippet of my code. Whenever I do not include the PasteSpecial arguments, the code below works, but when I include arguments, as seen below, the code gives me the error, "PasteSpecial Method of Range Class Failed".

```
xlWS1.Range("AF10").Copy

xlWS1.Range("AF11:AF27").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Why is this error occurring?

Thanks!

Comment: What's in AF10? Is there an actual formula or just data? Are you just trying to replicate what's in AF10 down to AF27?  You probably don't need a copy/paste here at all.

Comment: "AF10" is a cell. Row 10, Column AF. I am trying to only copy the formula (no formatting) from the cell AF10 to cells AF11:AF27. When I do this without arguments it works, but copies the formatting as well, which is what I do not want.

Comment: If you drop the `, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False`, does it still error?

Comment: Yes, it still does

Comment: How are the cells formatted? in my test ```x1WS1.Range("AF11:AF27").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas``` doesn't carry a text or fill color.

Comment: Do you have merged cells?

Comment: They are not merged. And the cells that I am pasting to just have a border around it, a fill color, and a number in it. I just tried to clear the contents of these pasted cells before copying and pasting, however, this also did not work and I got the same error

Comment: Do you guys think this might have anything to do with the fact that this macro is in Access? Because I wrote a macro that copies data from Access into an Excel spreadsheet and then I am now trying to format the spreadsheet that I copied the data into.

Comment: **Definitely**. Do you have a reference to the Excel Object library under Tools > References? Otherwise Access doesn't know what `xlPasteFormulas` is.

Comment: I did not and It works now. Thanks so much for the help everyone! I greatly appreciate all the effort you all put into helping me!

Answer (score 0):

The below code takes the formula in cell af10 and puts  it in each of the cells from af11 to af27. I'm not sure what formatting you don't want to carry, but this doesn't carry text or fill colors.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim i As Variant
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

Set rng1 = ws.Range("af10")
Set rng2 = ws.Range("af11:af27")

rng1.Copy

rng2.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry,  I probably should have been clearer in my original post, when I meant "copy formula" I meant in terms of the relative references. So this way did not work for me.